# How to execute host's Docker command from container?

Tags: python, docker, coreos

I want to write Docker containers management script in Python. However, since I use CoreOS, Python is not included as standard command. So, I am thinking of using Python Docker container (https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/python/) to execute my script. However, in that case the script will be executed in container's VM which doesn't have access to the host's Docker CLI.

Is there a way to use Python (or other programming languages not packaged in CoreOS), to manage host environment without installing it on the host machine?

PS, the script will do something like:

`docker run/rm/stop <another container>;`

Comment: What actions this script will do ?

Comment: docker run/rm/stop <another container>;

Comment: Why use a Python script and not a Shell one ?

Comment: @Erazihel Yes, currently I use bash script. But since I have more experience in Python, I would prefer to have it in Python (or even Go)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that what you're looking for is possible. Why don't you just install Python on your host anyway ?

Comment: Yes, it can be the easy solution. But reading about CoreOS & RancherOS philosophy (everything is Docker container), I wonder how this use case could be satisfied..

Comment: @Erazihel it is possible, see my answer below

Comment: @mattinbits Well, I didn't know that, thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make the Docker daemon reachable via HTTPS then you can communicate with the daemon from remote machines, or from within Docker containers. The instructions for enabling HTTPS in the daemon are here https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/

In short it involves creating client and server certificates (for security) and running the Docker daemon with a command such as

```
docker -d --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem \
--tlscert=server-cert.pem --tlskey=server-key.pem \
-H=0.0.0.0:2376
```

When running in this mode, you can use an appropriate client library for the programming language of your choice https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/remote_api_client_libraries/

There is one for python `docker-py` I haven't tried it but can say from experience this approach works using `docker-java` client library, having a Java program inside a container stopping and starting other containers.

Comment: Yeah, that's the article I was looking for. The docker-py library is presumably used by Compose, so it should be pretty good.

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that you can still make normal command line calls against the remote api if you install the docker client.

Answer (score 6):

You can either mount the docker binary and socket into the container:

```
$ docker run -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock debian docker --version
Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609
```

Or set up docker to allow remote access (I can't find a good reference for this at the minute).

You should also look at using the [Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) rather than making command line calls. There is a [python library](https://github.com/docker/docker-py) available to help you.

Comment: With your command I get `error while loading shared libraries:` so I tried `docker run -v /lib64:/lib64 -v /usr:/usr -v /lib:/lib -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock debian docker --version
` and it works

Comment: Yeah, this answer is old and only worked when Docker were distributing a static binary. With dynamic binaries the best plan is probably to install Docker in the container.

Answer (score 2):

A different way would be to use CoreOS toolbox to access python and exec docker. For example, my CoreOS machine running a simple python command from CoreOS to see docker process status":

```
core@zz1 ~ $ toolbox python -c 'import os;os.system("/media/root/usr/bin/docker -H unix:///media/root/var/run/docker.sock ps")'
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
2f5480ebc129        gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.12             "/usr/local/bin/etcd   47 minutes ago      Up 46 minutes                           k8s_etcd.3a160ccf_kube-dns-45.55.230.109_kube-system_790a48cfb2e2a5ae0abfcb6e3221275f_9d4fc659                   
ddbbc5e5033c        gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-03-11-001   "/skydns -addr=0.0.0   47 minutes ago      Up 47 minutes                           k8s_skydns.db942972_kube-dns-45.55.230.109_kube-system_790a48cfb2e2a5ae0abfcb6e3221275f_59835376                 
...
```

-g