# Docker - issue command from one linked container to another

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, continuous-delivery

I'm trying to set up a primitive CI/CD pipeline using 2 Docker containers -- I'll call them **jenkins** and **node-app**.  My aim is for the **jenkins** container to run a job upon commit to a GitHub repo (that's done).  That job should run a `deploy.sh` script on the **node-app** container.  Therefore, when a developer commits to GitHub, **jenkins** picks up the commit, then kicks off a job including automated tests (in the future) followed by a deployment on **node-app**.

The **jenkins** container is using the latest image ([Dockerfile)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/83ce6f6070f1670563a00d0f61d04edd62b78f4f/Dockerfile).

The **node-app** container's Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:latest
EXPOSE 80
WORKDIR /usr/src/final-exercise
ADD . /usr/src/final-exercise

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm
RUN cd /src/final-exercise; npm install

CMD ["node", "/usr/src/final-exercise/app.js"]
```

**jenkins** and **node-app** are linked using Docker Compose, and that `docker-compose.yml` file contains (updated, thanks to @alkis):

```
node-app:
  container_name: node-app
  build: .
  ports:
   - 80:80
  links:
   - jenkins
jenkins:
  container_name: jenkins
  image: jenkins
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
  volumes:
   - /home/ec2-user/final-exercise:/var/jenkins
```

The containers are built using `docker-compose up -d` and start as expected.  `docker ps` yields (updated):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED                 STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
69e52b216d48        finalexercise_node-app   "node /usr/src/final-"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                  node-app
5f7e779e5fbd        jenkins                  "/bin/tini -- /usr/lo"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   jenkins
```

I can ping **jenkins** from **node-app** and vice versa.

Is this even possible?  If not, am I making an architectural mistake here?

Thank you very much in advance, I appreciate it!

EDIT:
I've stumbled upon `nsenter` and easily entering a container's shell using [this](http://blog.docker.com/2014/06/why-you-dont-need-to-run-sshd-in-docker/) and [this](http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2014/01/27/access-a-container-without-ssh/).  However, these both assume that the origin (in their case the host machine, in my case the **jenkins** container) has Docker installed in order to find the PID of the destination container.  I can `nsenter` into **node-app** from the host, but still no luck from **jenkins**.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380569/717267

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63690421/10534470

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
node-app:
  build: .
  ports:
   - 80:80
  links:
   - finalexercise_jenkins_1

jenkins:
  image: jenkins
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
  volumes:
   - /home/ec2-user/final-exercise:/var/jenkins
```

Try the above. You are linking by image name, but you must use container name. 
In your case, since you don't specify explicitly the container name, it gets auto-generated like this

```
finalexercise : folder where your docker-compose.yml is located
node-app      : container configs tag
1             : you only have one container with the prefix finalexercise_node-app. If you built a second one, then its name will be finalexercise_node-app_2
```

The setup of the yml files:

```
node-app:
  build: .
  container_name: my-node-app
  ports:
   - 80:80
  links:
   - my-jenkins

jenkins:
  image: jenkins
  container_name: my-jenkins
  ports:
   - 8080:8080
  volumes:
   - /home/ec2-user/final-exercise:/var/jenkins
```

Of course you can specify a container name for the node-app as well, so you can use something constant for the communication.

**Update**

In order to test, log to a bash terminal of the jenkins container

```
docker exec -it my-jenkins bash
```

Then try to ping my-node-app, or even telnet for the specific port.

```
ping my-node-app:80
```

Or you could

```
telnet my-node-app 80
```

**Update**

What you want to do is easily accomplished by the `exec` [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).
From your host you can execute this (try it so you are sure it's working)

```
docker exec -i <container_name> ./deploy.sh
```

If the above works, then your problem delegates to executing the same command from a container. As it is you can't do that, since the container that's issuing the command (jenkins) doesn't have access to your host's docker installation (which not only recognises the command, but holds control of the container you need access to).

I haven't used either of them, but I know of two solutions

1. Use this official [guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/) to gain access to your host's docker daemon and issue docker commands from your containers as if you were doing it from your host.
2. Mount the docker binary and socket into the container, so the container acts as if it is the host (every command will be executed by the docker daemon of your host, since it's shared).

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625679/how-to-execute-hosts-docker-command-from-container) from SO gives some more insight about this issue.

Comment: That is extremely helpful as far as organizing my containers -- thank you.  However, I'm still struggling with figuring out how to initiate commands for my node-app container **from** my jenkins container.  For example, jenkins telling node-app that it needs to run `deploy.sh`.

Comment: The same applies. Give a name to your node-app container and use that as hostname while in jenkins, to communicate with the node-app. I've updated my answer to make it a little more clear

Comment: Appreciate that.  I've been able to ping the node-app container the entire time, however.  What I can't figure out is how to call the `deploy.sh` script from jenkins.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I used a [very helpful link](http://container-solutions.com/running-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/) in addition to alkis' answer.  My final solution involved what the author calls Docker-outside-of-Docker (DooD), whereby the **jenkins** container actually runs `docker exec -i node-app bash` and then passing in the deploy commands to the **node-app** container.  Please note that the -t flag in `docker exec -it node-app bash` in alkis' answer will not work, as you'll get a tty error.